# how to create an hybrid function from quicksort and insertion sort?

Tags: quicksort, insertion-sort

I want to design a new sort algorithm that combines the best of quicksort and insertion sort. At the begining I dont know if my the array is sorted or not. So, I need to choose an efficient one between quicksort and insertion to start. I will choose quicksort. How can I decide during the execution if it is bettwer to switch from quick-sort to insertion sort?
So, I think I need to add almost the same code in my new sort algorithm of quicksort and I need to add a new base case. This relation I think should reflect the relation between length of the input array and the recursion depth that hold for a well behaving quick-sort.

So since, the max tree depth (recursion) in quick sort is n and the min is logn, is it is correct my thinking to add the new base case as:

```
if len(less_than_pivot) == (n-1) :
  return insertion_sort(less_than_pivot)
elif len(greater_than_pivot)== n-1:
  return insertion_sort(greater_than_pivot)
```

less_than_pivot means the array including all the elements less than the pivot (same for greater_than_pivot) .

so in principle, i need for the hybrid sorting algorithm, consider the points where quicksort's performance might degrade (e.g., nearly sorted arrays) and switch to insertion sort accordingly.

Comment: Many existing sort methods (such as Java's Arrays.sort) use a combination of Quicksort and Insertion Sort, so look at existing implementations for ideas. Use insertion sort if the number of elements is small (for example, less than 20). Otherwise, choose the pivot carefully. For example, take 3 random elements and take the middle value as the pivot. Also, look at elements at regular intervals and determine if your array is mostly already sorted, in which case use Insertion Sort.